# How to add custom name in elastic search using JEST client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

How to add custom name to elastic search using JEST client?

For Example Using Spring data You can use custom name. Spring Data ES use Jackson. So, you can use `@JsonProperty("your_custom_name")` to enable custom name in ES Mapping

Answer (score 0):

With jest client for elasticsearch, you **need not specify any annotations** for the field names. The **variable name itself is used by jest client** to write data into elasticsearch. For example :

```
  class Article {

    @JestId
    private String documentId;

    private String author;

    private int pages;

 }
```

Writing the above class will generate the documents with field names as documentId, author and pages.

```
{
   "documentId" : "doc_01",
   "author" : "John Doe",
   "pages" : 3
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Jest client is using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for serialisation. So, you can use the @SerializedName annotation for custom name. Eg.

```
class Article {

  @JestId
  private String documentId;

  @SerializedName("author_name")
  private String authorName;

  @SerializedName("page_s")
  private int pages;

}
```